# QWC2 - Use Bing as a background map

Tags: qgis, qwc2

I have seen a number of question on this subject but I cannot find any examples.
I've successfully added other maps but I'm unable to display any Bing maps as background maps.

I have added the following code to themesConfig.json

```
"name":"bingR",
"type":"bing",
"source":"bing",
"provider":"BingRD",
"title":"Bing Road Map",
"thumbnail":"default.jpg",
"attribution":"Map data: &copy; <a href=\"http://www.microsoft.com/\">Bing</a>"
```

and in utils/ConfigProvider.js

```
BingRD: {
        options: {
            apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            name: 'RoadOnDemand'
        }
},
```

The 2 options match those required by components/map/layers/BingLayer.js
I can see calls to https://dev.virtualearth.net but the parameters/options are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to declare a new provider in ConfigProvider.js

Use this following background declaration in themesConfig.json:

```
    {
      "name": "bingR",
      "title":"Bing Road Map",
      "type": "bing",
      "thumbnail":"default.jpg",
      "attribution":"Map data: &copy; <a href=\"http://www.microsoft.com/\">Bing</a>",
      "options": {
        "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "name": "RoadOnDemand"
      }
    }
```

**EDIT**:

The right definition of BingMaps background layer is:

```
        {
          "name": "RoadOnDemand",
          "title":"Bing Road Map",
          "type": "bing",
          "thumbnail":"default.jpg",
          "source": "bing",
          "attribution":"Map data: &copy; <a href=\"http://www.microsoft.com/\">Bing</a>",
          "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I still do not get a background layer. I can see connection attempts to
```https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/bingR?uriScheme=https&include=ImageryProviders&key=undefined&c=en-us&jsonp=olc_76
```
where bingR is my name of the background layer.

Comment: What is the error when attempting to connect to this URL ? See in Network tab (Response tab) Development tools window of your browser.

Comment: URL
```https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/bingR?uriScheme=https&include=ImageryProviders&key=undefined&c=en-us&jsonp=olc_57```
Response```olc_57({
    "authenticationResultCode": "InvalidCredentials",
    "brandLogoUri": **removed**
    "errorDetails": ["Access was denied. You may have entered your credentials incorrectly, or you might not have access to the requested resource or operation."],
    "resourceSets": [],
    "statusCode": 401,
    "statusDescription": "Unauthorized",
    "traceId": "353de21d2b94474a9bd0d073e6db196b|DU00003038|0.0.0.1"
})```

Comment: I have edited my answer with a new definition. I am able to see Bing Maps background layer. Please test this definition.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. I had tried many variations but "name" being used for both the option value and the layer name confused me.